# Creating multicast events with std::tr1::function (or boost::function)

Tags: c++, stl, boost, delegates, tr1

I'm attempting to create C#-like multicast delegates and events using features from TR1. Or Boost, since boost::function is (mostly) the same as std::tr1::function. As a proof of concept I tried this:

```
template<typename T1>
class Event
{
private:
 typedef std::tr1::function<void (T1)> action;
 std::list<action> callbacks;

public:

 inline void operator += (action func)
 {
  callbacks.push_back(func);
 }

 inline void operator -= (action func)
 {
  callbacks.remove(func);
 }

 void operator ()(T1 arg1)
 {
  for(std::list<action>::iterator iter = callbacks.begin();
   iter != callbacks.end(); iter++)
  {
   (*iter)(arg1);
  }
 }
};
```

Which works, sort of. The line `callbacks.remove(func)` does not. When I compile it, I get the following error:

```
error C2451: conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal
```

Which is caused by line 1194 of the `list` header, which is in the `remove` function. What is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is exactly same problem: [comparing-stdtr1function-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89488/comparing-stdtr1function-objects)

(basically you can't compare functors, that's why erase or anything using operator== won't work)

Answer (score 5):

If you're you're looking for multicast delegates in C++, your best bet would be [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals2.html). You can also use [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind/bind.html) to make it possible to use member functions for callbacks.

You can look at my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211801/generic-member-function-pointer-help/2212136#2212136) for simple usage of Boost.Signals and Boost.Bind.

Boost.Signal provides lifetime management facilities to ensure that events are not published to subscribers that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Sutter's [Generalizing Observer](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184403873)