# making a std::funtion that points to two functions c++

Tags: c++, std-function

If I have two functions

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

void bar()
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}
```

and I have a function pointer

```
std::function<void()> v;
```

and I want `v()` to print

```
1
2
```

Comment: Use a lambda? What is your question?

Comment: @hyde so that would be `[](){foo();bar();}` right?

Comment: What would you expect if the return type was *not* `void`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::function`'s definition of target is `const T* target() const`, which means it can only store one target.

[This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226691/creating-multicast-events-with-stdtr1function-or-boostfunction), the situation you're describing is known as "delegate multicasting" in CLR/.NET in the context of event-handlers.

There are a few possible solutions:

1. The first is to use a lambda or other function to define the multicast manually:

   ```
   function<void()> v = []() {
       foo();
       bar();
   };
   v();
   ```
2. The second is to define your own full `std::function`-esque which supports a variable number of targets. You could do it with a `template` array (thus avoiding runtime use of `vector`)... or just use a `vector` anyway.
3. A third option is to simply wrap `vector` anyway (warning: pseudocodeish):

   ```
   template<class FuncType>
   class MulticastFunction {
   private:
       vector<std::function<FuncType>> targets;
   public:
       void operator()() {
           for(auto& target : this->targets) {
               target();
           }
       }
       void addTarget(FuncType& target) {
           this->targets->push_back( target );
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   MulticastFunction<void()> mc;
   mc.addTarget( foo );
   mc.addTarget( bar );
   mc();
   ```

Comment: You probably want `target` to be by value or const ref, so it can bind to lambdas for example